# mvn: command not found

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to run a pipeline with jenkinsfile on a specific for which I don't have access to manage the path. But I'm having this error can any one know how to solve this one?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to install Maven on the build agent executing the job. An alternative by Jenkins is that it can install Maven for you. This can be configured in the *Global Tool Configuration* of the Jenkins Master.

If you are really only allowed to modify the `Jenkinsfile`, you could first download and unpack maven into some local directory and then call it from there.